# querying using two drop boxes in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, forms, php-5.3

I have two drop down boxes using the code below:

```
<form method="post" action="">      
            <select name='defect' value=''>
                <option>Rotten</option>
                <option>Split</option>
                <option>WheelCut</option>
                <option>Broken</option>
                <option>Quality</option>
            </select>
                      is equal to:
            <select name='quality' value=''></option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
            </select>
        <input type="submit" name="query" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

I am trying to make it so that after clicking on the submit button it changes the following query...

```
SELECT   id, mile, yard, gps_lat, gps_long, rotten, split, wheel_cut, broken, quality
FROM database WHERE gps_lat IS NOT NULL AND ????? (e.g. broken=2) ORDER BY mile, yard
```

- how do I combine the two user inputs (e.g. broken value=2)
- Do I need to use a switch statement to change the query for each possibly?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Neil

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that query?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT id, mile, yard, gps_lat, gps_long, rotten, split, wheel_cut, broken, quality
FROM database WHERE gps_lat IS NOT NULL';

switch($_POST['defect'])
{
        case 'Rotten': $defect = 'rotten'; break;
        case 'Split': $defect = 'split'; break;
        case 'WheelCut': $defect = 'wheel_cut'; break;
        case 'Broken': $defect = 'broken'; break;
        case 'Quality': $defect = 'quality'; break;
        default: $defect = ''; break;
}

switch($_POST['quality'])
{
        case 1: $quality = 1; break;
        case 2: $quality = 2; break;
        case 3: $quality = 3; break;
        case 4: $quality = 4; break;
        default: $quality = 0; break;
}

if($defect != '' && $quality != 0)
{
    $sql .= ' AND '.$defect.' = '.$quality;
}

$sql .= ' ORDER BY mile, yard';
?>
```

**Edited** to make a bit better

Answer (score 1):

To prevent hardcoded logic, you can  move it to server side. Good solution is to use dynamic SQL to build filter query. You can write stored procedure with XML which will contain column name and filtered value. Here is your example:

```
    DECLARE @xml XML= '<root><select name="defect" value="">
                <option>Rotten</option>
                <option>Split</option>
                <option>WheelCut</option>
                <option>Broken</option>
                <option>Quality</option>
            </select>
            <select name="quality" value="" type="int">
                <option>2</option>
            </select></root>'
DECLARE @sSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)   = 'SELECT   id, mile, yard, gps_lat, gps_long, rotten, split, wheel_cut, broken, quality
FROM database WHERE gps_lat IS NOT NULL' ;
WITH    c AS ( SELECT   a.b.value('../@name[1]', 'nvarchar(128)') ColumnName ,
                        a.b.value('.', 'nvarchar(128)') VALUE ,
                        a.b.value('../@type[1]', 'nvarchar(128)') [Type]
               FROM     @xml.nodes('root/select/*') a ( b )
             )
    SELECT  @sSQl = @sSQL + ' AND ' + c.ColumnName + '='
            + CASE WHEN ISNULL(c.TYPE, '') != 'int' THEN CHAR(39)
                   ELSE ''
              END + c.VALUE
            + CASE WHEN ISNULL(c.TYPE, '') != 'int' THEN CHAR(39)
                   ELSE ''
              END
    FROM    c
SET @sSQL = @sSQL + ' ORDER BY mile, yard'
SELECT  @sSQL
```

Result will be:

```
SELECT   id, mile, yard, gps_lat, gps_long, rotten, split, wheel_cut, broken, quality  FROM database WHERE gps_lat IS NOT NULL AND defect='Rotten' AND defect='Split' AND defect='WheelCut' AND defect='Broken' AND defect='Quality' AND quality=2 ORDER BY mile, yard
```

Note that you can build filters where user can check several checkboxes.(In example user checks  all checkboxes in "defect"). In that way you can prepare your application for future enhancement.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Dalex! I'm kind of a beginner to PHP and your solution is fairly complex! Thank you for your time! cheers